# Download S3 objects in a single operation

Tags: java, amazon-s3

Please, what is the best strategy to download all objects stored on AWS S3?

I need to offer some feature to final users of our system that enable them to download in a single operation all stored objects - .rar or .zip would be great!

I'm using AWS SDK for Java.

Tks.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no in-built capability** in Amazon S3 to combine/zip files together.

**Your application would need to create such a file**, then upload it to S3 to make it available for download.

There are a number of utilities that can assist with this:

- [s3-zip 
  Download selected files from an Amazon S3 bucket as a zip file](https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-zip)
- [S3 Zipper: How to Securely Provide a Zip Download of a S3 File Bundle](http://engineroom.teamwork.com/how-to-securely-provide-a-zip-download-of-a-s3-file-bundle/)
- [PHP library to efficiently stream contents from an AWS S3 bucket or folder as a zip file](https://github.com/jmathai/s3-bucket-stream-zip-php)

Answer (score 0):

I found https://www.cloudzipinc.com/ allowed me to zip my bucket's files and also provided a csv table of contents for the zips.  Then my users could download the zips that contained the files they needed.